# Connect Azure Sql with Python Azure Function?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I need to connect Azure Sql Db from Python Azure Function.
Azure SQL is linked with Azure account(A) and Python Azure function is linked with another account(B). I am able to fetch data from within same account(B) Sql DB from Python Azure Function but when i am trying to create connection with sql db of other Azure Account(A) from Account(B), it is giving me the error.

What i tried:

```
server = "XXXX.database.windows.net"
database = "KDSKDNK"
username = "ABC" 
password = "##$%fJNSK" 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
DATABASE_CONNECTION = f'mssql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION,fast_executemany = True)
connection = engine.connect()
```

The above code is working fine for the sql database which is in the same account(B) but it not working for azure account(A) DB.

Error:

```
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access). To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database). (47073) (SQLDriverConnect)').
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either run this from a resource running on the same network as the SQL DB using the private address since you are using a public address that is being Denied access to. Or you need to enable Public access which is less secure then you can run it from anywhere.

Comment: Is there a way, we can whitelist the IP Address of Account A Function App in Account B?

Comment: Yes of course, when you are on your SQL DB Page, look for the shield icon called Set server Firewall. However, you will still need to enable public access. But with the server Firewall, you can allow only the client IPs you want to have access to the server.